# Plot Scaling Problem

Tags: bayesian, data-visualization, likelihood, prior

I am trying to implement the following code in R

$\theta \sim Beta(a=1,b=1)$

$x|\theta \sim Bin(N=5,\theta)$

$\theta|x \sim Beta(a+\sum x_{i},b+\sum N-\sum x_{i})$

`theta<-seq(0,1,length=100)
prior<-dbeta(theta,1,1)
N<- 5
data<-rbinom(length(theta),N,theta)
likelihood<- theta^(sum(data))*(1-theta)^(length(data)*N-sum(data))
posterior<-dbeta(theta,sum(data),length(data)*5-sum(data))`

My problem is that when I try to plot them the scaling is completely different.

Comment: What do you mean by "the scaling"?

Comment: @DemetriPananos   The max. value of the posterior distribution is 17.81804 , while the max. value of  the prior is 1 and likelihood is 3.711578e-151. So when I plot them altogether the ylim's for each distributions is different.This has as a result likelihoods plot beings a flat line.

Comment: Is your goal to plot posterior and prior on the same plot to show differences between the two?

Comment: posterior code should be $dbeta(theta,sum(data)+1,1+length(data)*5-sum(data))$ since $a=b=1$

Comment: @DemetriPananos My goal is to plot Likelihood,Prior,Posterior on the same plot in order to show that the uninformative prior is flat where the Likelihood has mass and also to compare the Prior and Posterior .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things might explain why you aren't getting the result you want.  First, when you call `rbinom`, you pass `theta` as the probability argument, but theta is an array, which means your data generating process isn't correct and consequently neither is the posterior.  Second, your posterior parameters are off by 1 since you don't pass the priors parameters into the posterior density.

Here is a way to plot what you want.

```r
#Need a fixed value for data generating process
true_theta = 0.4

#This is our parameter space, not our true theta
theta = seq(0,1,length.out = 1001)

N<-5 #Number of bernoulli experiments
num_trials = 1 #Num experiments

#Flat prior
prior = dbeta(theta,1,1)

#Note here that true_theta is the prob argument.  
#Results in a vector of length num_trials, each with N bernoulli trials
data<-rbinom(num_trials,N,true_theta)

likelihood<-theta^(sum(data))*(1-theta)^(N*num_trials-sum(data))

posterior = dbeta(theta,1+sum(data), 1+N*num_trials-sum(data))


#Divide by max of each function so they are plotted on a reasonable scale
plot(theta,prior/max(prior), type = 'l')
lines(theta,likelihood/max(likelihood), col='blue')
lines(theta,posterior/max(posterior), col = 'red')
```

This results in

[image]

Note that because you have a flat prior, the likelihood is the posterior.  Changing the prior results in something that may look like this

[image]

Is this what you were expecting?

Comment: Yes,the first plot helped me a lot.I really missed the step were you divide with the max value each function.This is a standard procedure in order to make reasonable scale ??

Comment: I think it is just a clever trick, really.